# fxShow and fxHide are not hiding/showing nav menu

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

fxShow and fxHide are not hiding/showing the menu options in my code, I've tested the other attributes of flex-layout like flexLayout and flexLayoutAlign and all of those work.

I have tried code that I copied exactly from the Flex-Layout github page and it doesn't work.

Here's what I am testing, I want to hide the menu on screens that are larger than medium:

```xml
<mat-toolbar>
  <div fxLayout="row">
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">About</a>
  </div>
  
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu"  fxHide fxShow.lt-md>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

The result is that the menu does not hide regardless of the screen size and is shown at all times.  No error messages and when I look at the attributes in developer tools, those attributes are listed.

Comment: If I don't get it wrong, you want to hide the `menu` button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview)

> The `<mat-menu>` element does not render anything. It is opened via
>   application of the `matMenuTriggerFor` directive.

In your case, I think you want to hide the `menu` button instead

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" fxHide fxShow.lt-md>Menu</button>
```

Here is a demo on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gn2fjf).

Comment: Thank you! you are right about it being on the wrong element, I put it on the button, but the button will not show on screens less than medium, it is hidden at all times.  If I change the logic to fxShow and fxHide.gt-md it doesn't work either, any other ideas?

Comment: I think that maybe your screen and stackblitz is not enough to trigger the breakpoint, it worked fine on my 14' screen with `gt-sm`. Could you test on a larger screen?

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Comment: How can I hide the menu itself (the trigger has other elements inside, that need be visible) for screen widths less then medium? `I tried <mat-menu #myMenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" fxHide fxShow.gt-md>` and it does nit work.

Comment: If the menu is opened and screen resizes it stays open instead of hiding it together with the button.

Answer (score -1):

since you want it to be shown by default but hidden on screens larger then medium, then it should be

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" fxShow fxHide.lt-md>
 <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
 <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```